# Go 1.17: How to log error with the stack trace

Tags: go

How to log the line number and file name of the error? I tried `%w`, zap logger's `Errorw`, but its not working as good as `github.com/pkg/errors`, which is sadly archived. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    stderrors "errors"

    pkgerrors "github.com/pkg/errors"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

func main() {
    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()

    logger.Errorf("Hello %v %w", "error", stderrors.New("some error"))
    logger.Errorw("Hello", "error", stderrors.New("some error"))

    logger.Errorf("Hello %v %w", "error", pkgerrors.New("some error"))
    logger.Errorw("Hello", "error", pkgerrors.New("some error"))
}
```

Here is the playgroud code for the same: https://go.dev/play/p/PO3dFrK5ua6

Comment: With zap, would be great! If I am able to log it in general also, I will just pass a param to Errorw only.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/go-errors

But I want to just say that it's not good practice to do this in Go. It's best to float your errors down the function calls and print them out after.

```
func HandleApiReq() (*APIResponse, error) {
    // ...logic...error handling
    gwres, err := QueryGateway()
    // ...logic...error handling
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to process API request on endpoint %s: %v", endpoint, err)
}

func QueryGateway() (*GatewayResult, error) {
    // ...logic...error handling
    dbres, err := GetFromDB()
    // ...logic...error handling
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("error received from db in gateway %s: %v", gw.Name(), err)
}

func GetFromDb() (*DBResult, error) {
    // ...logic...error handling
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to get from db. Db err received on table %s: %v", tableName err)
}
```

So your end output assuming your db gets an error will naturally be built from all your previous errors like:
***failed to process API request on endpoint /products: error received from db in gateway stock_gateway: failed to get from db. Db err received on table name products: Deadlock occurred***

Comment: Use the `%w` wrap formatting verb instead of `%v` when chaining error values - it allows `errors.As` & `errors.Is` to capture or identify specific errors for special handling higher up the call stack.

Comment: I like this pattern to augment the error with additional strings at each point on the function call stack, but I can't figure out how to combine that with the example linked on go-errors where the error is wrapped, then the stack trace is retrieved/printed later. When I try to use both techniques I get "interface conversion: error is *fmt.wrapError, not *errors.Error "

Comment: @MattG Go is very pedantic about types. I am assuming you need to maybe assign it to a var of the correct interface or cast it. In any case, I am not sure why you would want to use errors package unless you are in Go 1.12 or lower. Here is a good qn explaining why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933650/whats-the-difference-between-errors-wrapf-errors-errorf-and-fmt-errorf

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this,

```
log.New(os.Stdout, "ERROR\t", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "but its not working as good as `github.com/pkg/errors`" means, but `logger.Errorw("Hello", "error", pkgerrors.New("some error"))` seems to work well for me? Zap logger logs two fields, `error` and `errorVerbose`. `errorVerbose` is the output of `%+v` formatting which includes full stack trace of the error.

If you would like for zap to add a stack trace for errors which do not have one, then you can enable its [`AddStacktrace` option](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#AddStacktrace).

And if you are complaining that `github.com/pkg/errors` worked fine for you, but it is now archived, you can use maintained [`gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors`](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) instead, which works as drop-in replacement. (Disclaimer: I am its maintainer.)

But if you are complaining that stack traces with newlines and tabs, all cramped into one string inside JSON, are hard to read, then you are right. So you can instead do ([demo](https://go.dev/play/p/eohMxALXesj)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

func main() {
    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()

    e, _ := json.Marshal(errors.New("some error"))
    logger.Errorw("Hello", "error", json.RawMessage(e))
}
```

This encodes the error as JSON and stack trace is also a JSON array of objects. So it is easy to extract file name and line number of the error, without having to parse them out of a string. Output (rewrapped):

```json
{
  "level": "error",
  "msg": "Hello",
  "error": {
    "error": "some error",
    "stack": [
      {
        "name": "main.main",
        "file": "/tmp/sandbox1042083031/prog.go",
        "line": 13
      },
      {
        "name": "runtime.main",
        "file": "/usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/proc.go",
        "line": 267
      },
      {
        "name": "runtime.goexit",
        "file": "/usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s",
        "line": 1650
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Errors made with `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` can be converted to JSON, which we use here. And other errors not made with `gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors` can still be converted with it to JSON by using `errors.Formatter` ([demo](https://go.dev/play/p/rkJR3gU2fbd)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    stderrors "errors"

    "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

func main() {
    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()

    e, _ := json.Marshal(errors.Formatter{stderrors.New("some error")})
    logger.Errorw("Hello", "error", json.RawMessage(e))
}
```

Output (rewrapped):

```json
{
  "level": "error",
  "msg": "Hello",
  "error": {
    "error": "some error"
  }
}
```